# Python find string ( unknown) in txt file

Tags: python

I know how to find string in text file.

The problem is that I don't know the string since every time I have text file the string is different but in the sam location in the file.
The string I'm looking for is a token that is changed, but I know it contained 20 char's for instance.

The flow.
I'm running API that creates the text file with a token that indont know in advance.
I want to find the token in th3 file and I don't know to what to compare it since it changed all time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow. You need to provide some attempt, something to work off, with concrete questions. This is not a place where people order code from others. Show some example data and what approach you have tried, with specifics on what is not working. Otherwise, this question will soon be closed.

As a step on the way, if the token is at the same location, why don't you just read on the file and reference that location in the buffer?

Comment: What do you mean by placing the token in same location in the file? Except this token, rest of the file is same always ? Please clarify

Comment: Hi.Yes file is the same always.

Comment: Hi.Yes file is the same ..just token is changed and i want to pull it out tonuse it..but i dont know it in advance..

Answer (score 0):

`Use Regular expressions.`

Let's say your file have the content "a quick brown fox jumps over the **TOKEN** lazy dog and any other animal". You can fetch the token using findall() method of re module.

```
     >> import re
     >> f = open(file_path, 'r')
     >> contents = f.read()
     >> tokens_list = re.findall(r'.*over the (.*) lazy dog.'*, contents)
```

Note that the above result is a list, you need to fetch the token out of this list.

```
    >> token = tokens_list[0]
    >> fp.close()
```

PS: Analyze the regular expression as per your file, and use the findall() method.